The BottomSheetDialog unexpectedly closes after capturing or cropping an image on Samsung and Vivo devices
I am developing an Android application that displays a BottomSheetDialog.
When the user selects an option in the dialog, I request camera permission. Once the user grants permission, I open the camera for the user to take a photo. After capturing the photo, the user can crop it.
However, the BottomSheetDialog closes after cropping, and sometimes it dismisses immediately after capturing the image, which I do not want. This issue occurs only on Samsung and Vivo mobile devices.
Dialog opens:

Requesting Permissions:


Capture / crop photo:


The dialog automatically closes afterwards:

I don't want the BottomSheetDialog to close after cropping the image, how can I fix this?

Images are not showing, and you have repeated text. This question should be cleaned up after reviewing the help for adding images.
